# Reports with page footers ...?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, reports

I don't really get the behaviour of QGIS new reports (3.X) ...

I inserted an attribute table in a report. this table is spanning over several pages. I would like to create a **page footer** with the page numbering (current page and total amount of pages).

That seems quite trivial ... but ... can QGIS reports do that ?

I'm not in the case of an atlas.

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS reports, the footer is the last *page*, not the footer of each page as you would expect in `*.doc` files, for example.

To add variable text to each page of the report, one needs to add labels with expressions.

- Add a label object
- Insert an expression like `[% @atlas_layername %]`

If you try with `[% @layout_page %]`, however, the number always remains "1"; we would need a `@report_page` variable, which at the moment is not available.

Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: i'm in the case of an attribute table spanning over several pages ... i don't get what u mention in step 3 _"increasing it when the controlling field changes"_ ... i'm not in the case of an atlas where you would have one feature per page ..

Comment: You are right, my previous answer only addressed the "footer" part.
I created a similar question, and relative answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/325909/142513