# Adding page number in QGIS Report?

Tags: qgis, reports

Adding page numbers in QGIS Layouts can be done with the `[% @layout_page %]` expression. In Reports, however, the `[% @layout_page %]` expression always remains "1"

How do we insert the page number in a Report?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We would need a `@report_page` variable, which at the moment is not available.

However there is a:

### Workaround

1. Create a new integer field in your layer, let's call this field `pagenum`.
2. Sort the features by the controlling field (i.e. the one you select as `Field` in the left pane of the Report editor).
3. Fill `pagenum` with sequential numbers, increasing it when the controlling field changes.
4. Create a label in the Report editor.
5. Insert the expression `[% "pagenum" %]`.
6. Export the report.

### Page 42 of 314

You can go one step further, and insert an expression to compute the total number of pages:

`Page number: [% "pagenum" %] of [% count_distinct(  "pagenum"  ) + 1 %]`

The `+ 1` here is for taking into account the header page, if any.

[image]

Comment: I don't see how i could use this solution in the case i told you in my [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325896/reports-with-page-footers) ... or maybe i'm getting something wrong ...