# Is there a variable for the numerotation of the pages in the layout report workspace of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, reports, qgis-variable

I want to add the page numbers as it is possible with the layout atlas workplace, however I cannot find a similar variable to use in the report.

Comment: Take a look a this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/325910/197233). It may help you display page numbers in your QGIS report.